# Orchard CMS - How to [sort/order] the Manage Content list in the Dashboard?

Tags: orchardcms, taxonomy, dashboard

using Orchard CMS, how does one under [Manage Content] Content > Content Items in the Admin Dashboard add/extend the ability to order the content items by "something" other than [recently created / modified / published]?  I haven't been using Orchard long, but this is becoming a real sore spot when I have close to a hundred items of varying types; "it makes working in the backend very tiresome, and exceptionally confusing for the end-user."

**Ultimately, I would love to order by taxonomy terms I have attached to my pages etc., but I'm open to any suggestions from the community?**

I also noted that Bertrand Le Roy had once created a 'TheTree' module for such circumstances, but checking the gallery [and his Git projects], I couldn't find it.

Thanks for your input, PP

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about editing that content index directly, you can probably override [the view in question](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Core/Contents/Views/Admin/List.cshtml) but I'm not sure how.

Seeing as this has gone unanswered for 5 days now I thought I would throw in one solution that I do know, which would be to do what the `Orchard.Search` module does. It has a feature within it called `Orchard.Search.Content` which adds a new tab to the Content Items page:

[image: Search tab]

You can add third level tab links to pages using `.LocalNav()`. To produce the effect above [this code](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Search/ContentAdminMenu.cs) is used:

```
    public void GetNavigation(NavigationBuilder builder) {
        builder.Add(T("Content"),
            menu => menu
                .Add(T("Search"), "1.5", item => item.Action("Index", "Admin", new {area = "Orchard.Search"}).LocalNav())
            );
    }
```

It does the rest using some standard code which you can see if you search the Orchard.Search project for the string `[OrchardFeature("Orchard.Search.Content")]` - it's all packaged up into just a few files within that module.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the support @rtpHarry. Yeah, the search solution is a little tedious - but I'm going to give it a fair road test before discarding it, and who knows, it may suffice and be perfectly satisfactory - though not ideal ;)